# Python - Using str.replace with a wildcard

Tags: python

I'm trying to rename folder names named with this pattern: FOLDERNAME (###)

I'm trying to get rid of (###), a series of numbers of random length.

I would like to use str.replace as show below to do it, but I'm not sure I can use a wildcard this way...

```
folderdir = os.listdir(path)            # Listing the folder names
for foldername in folderdir:
    output = foldername.replace("(*)", "")
    rename()
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Nope, `str.replace` won't work.  You need [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

e.g.:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\(.*\)', '', 'foobar (###)')
'foobar '
```

Comment: Was going to use the other solution, but this is cleaner (and it works too). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If the "(###)" is always at the end.

```
output = foldername.rpartition("(")[0]
```

Comment: Hmm, went for that. I'm new to python and it seems a little more simple! (even if it's messier...) Thanks!